# Vertical alignment of figures within tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.30\paperwidth}p{0.30\paperwidth}p{0.30\paperwidth}}
    \rowcolor{gray} &   & \\[4ex]
\rowcolor{gray} \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{1cm} \textcolor{white}{\Large \textbf{ProjektFormidlingNord}}} & \\[5ex] 
    \input{into_table.tex} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{nav.eps}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

which returns the following:
[image]

If I remove the image, the table on the left that is created by an external `.tex` file is nicely aligned at the top. I dont understand why the alignment on the left table should be affected by a `.svg` figure in the next column.

I hope some of you can expand my knowledge on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two cells as always are aligned on their baselines. By default a tabular is `[c]` aligned so its baseline goes through its centre, and images have the reference point in the bottom left corner, so the bottom of the image lines with the centre of the tabular.

You could use `[b]` on the tabular so its reference point was the baseline of the bottom row or use

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics....`
```

(or some fraction of `\height`) to move the reference point of the image. the `adjustbox` package gives a nicer syntax to adjusting the reference point of images.

Comment: thanks, but raisebox gave me the following: http://i.imgur.com/v5MRD4X.png

Comment: @Kristian60 yes you raised (lowered) it too far, if you use -\height it moves the baseline to the top so now the top of the image aligns with bottom of table -0.5\height might be right but it's a visual thing, you sometimes need to tune it by hand

Comment: -0.5\height was just what i needed. I couldent grasp the syntax of raisebox, but now its there. Thank you much.